# Combining many files with different organization and different shared values

Tags: python, r, file, merge, annotations

I have downloaded 100 gene expression data sets from NCBI GEO and associated all possible annotations with each one. Each file consists of rows that are genes and columns of various annotations and then expression data. However, because these all come from different sources and platforms, there is not a uniform way of labeling them. Some use the gene name (yfgA for example) while some use the standard name (b1029 for example) while others use completely different naming conventions. The organization and naming of the annotation columns also vary among files.

I would like to combine all of the files together so I have gene expression values for all experiments for each gene, but because the annotations are all over the place, traditional merging or combining methods in R or python don't seem like they will work for me. It will also take far to long to do this individually, so I'd like some way to automate it (as I have another 10,000 files waiting to do this for as well).

I would like a file where rows are each gene, columns are the different annotations possible and then all the gene expression data.

Any help or advice would be really appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't look like a question about programming, but rather where to find a data base that contains the different names for each gene. Or is there enough information in your data to create such a data base?

Comment: Thanks Fabian. Yeah, one option I hadn't thought of was using a database. I will attempt to create one from the files I have.